# jQuery/AJAX, retrieving a string that my method returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code-behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
    public string GetMessage() {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (Global.sAppPath + "/alt/importantMsg.xml");

        string message = null;

        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (reader.IsStartElement ()) {
                switch (reader.Name.ToString ()) {

                case "Message":
                    message = reader.ReadString();
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }

        return message;
    }
```

And I want to retrieve the message (the string that the code-behind returns) using jQuery. So I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.get("isoServe.asmx/GetMessage", function(data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

});

But this is not working for me. It's like I can't get a hole through. What am I doing wrong?
I also tried this:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "isoServe.asmx/GetMessage",
        data: "message", 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But this last piece of code, I am very unsure about. How should the "data" be given in this one.

---

The example below, does work (using xmlhttp). But I want to use jQuery

```
    function getMsg() {
  var msg = "";
  xmlhttp = gus.tie = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    { 
      msg = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.textContent;
      alert("Msg: " + msg + ": fra getMsg()"); 
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "isoServe.asmx/GetMessage", false);
  xmlhttp.send();

  return msg;
}
```

Comment: the success callback has the `data` parameter: `success: function(data){ alert(data);}`, find documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks, this was left out by mistake, cus of c&p. It doesn't make any difference, it still wont alert

Comment: Are you sure the url is corect? What happens if you visit the url directly in your browser

Comment: Yes the url is correct. If I use xmlhttp, then I can come through to that url. But I don't wanna use xmlhttp, since I am having trouble with status 0, and searching about this error, suggested to use JQuery

Comment: is the returned string a valid json string?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, for some reason the referenced file from the url had been deleted. That's why it wouldn't find it. I have a lot of debugging to do it seems, omg. Wish me luck.
Thanks for your time